# Elasticsearch query filter combination issue

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-dsl

Im trying to understand why the below elasticsearch query does not work.

EDIT:

The fields mentioned in the query are from different indices. For example Filter has classification field which is in a different index to the fields mentioned in the query string.

The expectation of the filter query is that when the user searches specifically on classification field i.e. secret or protected then the values are displayed. Else if the user searches for any other field from a different index for example firstname or person, then it should not consider any filter applied as firstname or person is not part of the filter

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
                    "filter": {
                        "terms": {
                            "classification": [
                                "secret",
                                "protected"
                            ]
                        }
            },
            "must": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "*john*",
                    "fields": [
                        "classification",
                        "firstname",
                        "releasability",
                        "person"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result expected is john in the field person is returned. This works when there is no filter applied in the above code as

```
{
    "query": {
     
                    

                "query_string": {
                   "query": "*john*",
                    "fields": [
                        "classification",
                        "firstname",
                        "releasability",
                        "person"
                    ]
                }
            
        
    }
}
```

The purpose of the filter is only to filter records when the said fields contain the values mentioned, otherwise it should work for all values.

Why is it not producing the results for john and only producing results for classification values only?

Comment: can you share some sample data ?

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, and thank you for your response. the fields are all from different indices. so in your example both the fields are from the same index. But mine has different indices. So classification field is from a different index than to a person. So when the query runs for Person field it should work independant of the fields in filter? is my understanding correct?

Comment: please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this was what you wanted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Adding a working example with sample index data and search query.**

To know more about Bool query refer this official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

**Index Data:**
Index data in `my_index` index

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "title":"b"
}
{
    "name":"Johns",
    "title":"a"
}
```

Index data in `my_index1` index

```
{
    "classification":"protected"
}
{
    "classification":"secret"
}
```

**Search Query :**

`POST http://localhost:9200/_search`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "classification": [
                    "secret",
                    "protected"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "*john*",
                  "fields": [
                    "name",
                    "title"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "John",
          "title": "b"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Johns",
          "title": "a"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "classification": "secret"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "classification": "protected"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Yes, the result is exactly what i wanted. Thanks a lot